# PSPad formatting gets lost with type="text/javascript"

Tags: formatting, editor, syntax-highlighting

Whenever I code the following inside an HTML document within PSPad (a free code editor):

```
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the `<script>` tag becomes gray.

When I remove  or split up the word `script` inside `text/javascript`, everything is fine. Is this a bug, or how can I still have formatting colors in a `<script>` tag with this `type` attribute?

Hopefully this image clearifies what I mean:

[image: PSPad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I do not have this issue anymore. I don't know how comes, but restarting PSPad was a workaround apparently. Also, I can't reproduce it at the moment anymore, so I'll forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it is the Javascript tag's highlighter background.

In the Settings menu you have the Highlighters Settings where you can change all highlighters.

Different languages in a document can have their own highlighter colors and the highlighter can be individually set on/off or customised for all languages.